# 2 assignment questions in complex analysis which couldn't be discussed

Tags: complex-analysis

These 2 questions were part of assignment given and couldn't be discussed due to pendamic. So, I am asking them here.

1. According to Riemann Mapping Theorem, any simply connected region other than $\mathbb{C} $ is conformally equivalent to Unit disc with centre z=0 . Is the result valid for $\mathbb{C} $ ?

I couldn't thinking of reasoning behind it and couldn't find anything related on google and Wikipedia.

2.Let f be homomorphic on a region $\Omega$ with no zeroes. If there is a homomorphic function $h$ such that $h'= f'/f$ show that $f$ has a homomorphic logarithm  on $\Omega$ . Also show that $h$ need not exist and give sufficient condition on $\Omega$ that ensures existence of $h$.

> Attempt : I thought of integrating $h'= f'/f$ from which I got $h =\log f(z)$.

But question says that I am wrong as h need not exist. So, kindly tell me what mistake I am making and what is right way to do it.

Comment: 1. No... Liouville theorem forbids the existence of injective holomorphic maps $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow D$. 2. Differentiate $fe^{-h}$ to show that $f$ has a logarithm. But note that $f$ has a logarithm *if such a function $h$ exists*. In certain domains it’s not hard to construct functions without a logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for first question: Liouville's Theorem applies to $\mathbb C$ but not to regions like the open unit disk.

Logarithms in the complex plane are more complicated than logarithms of posotive numbers. Your argument using $log f$ does not make sense.

Show that derivative of $e^{-h}f$ is $0$ to prove that there is an analytic function $\phi$ such that $e^{\phi}=f$.
For the last part use the fact that the identity function $f$ on  $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is a counter example.  If $\frac {f'} f (z)=\frac  1 z$ is the derivative of some  analytic function then its integral over the unit circle would be $0$, but the integral is $2\pi i$.

A sufficient condition for existence of $h$ is simply connectedness of the domain .

Comment: For 1st your hint was not sufficient for me to get the reason behind the negation. Can you please elaborate answer of 1st question?

Comment: Suppose there is  a one-to-one analytic function $f: \mathbb C \to D$ where $D$ is  the open unit disk. Apply Liouville's Theorem.  @Tim

Comment: "Show that derivative of $e^{-h} f$ is 0". By proving this I got $e^{-h} f = c $ . But how to prove constant  c is equal to 1? Also, it seems that in last 3 lines of your answer you have done some typo. Can you please check that? Thanks!!

Comment: @Tim $c$ need nit be $1$ but it is non-zero. Any non-zero complex number $c$ can be written as $e^{d}$ for some complex number $d$. So $f=ce^{h}=e^{d+h}$. What is the mistake in the last 3 lines? Please be specific.

Comment: I am sorry, there is no typo. Can you please tell why integral over unit circle should be zero? Which result you used?

Comment: The integral over a  closed contour of the derivative of a holomorphic function is always $0$. $\int_0^{1} h'(\gamma (t))\gamma '(t)dt =h(\gamma (t)|_0^{1}=h(\gamma (1))-h(\gamma (0))=0$. This is just FTC. @Tim

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!